# Android:BaseAdapter Implementation of List View ,detailing to of list items

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have implemented BaseApater using View Holder. I am able to generate list properly. But with each associated list there is description associated which I want to display on another screen when user clicks on list item.What is the best way ti implement it

Comment: You can follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is add an onItemClickedListener.
So you can intent a new activity and you should pass the properly value of the item to this activity.